# API quota for Gmail REST API and Gmail IMAP using same console app

Tags: google-api, imap, gmail-api, gmail-imap, google-console-developer

Gmail IMAP is also moved to Oauth2 authentication. So, we are using **same console app** for Gmail REST API and Gmail IMAP.
**My Question :** For IMAP and REST API the quota allotted will be shared or each has its own quota? If so can any one share quota for Gmail IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

IMAP and GMAIL REST API has its own quota, [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota)  is subject to a daily usage limit that applies to all requests made from your application. For daily usage it has 1,000,000,000 quota units per day and 250 quota units per user per second rate limit.

For IMAP mail client, the maximum number of recipient allowed for each eamil is 500 receipts.

To view usage limits for your project or to request an increase to your quota, open API library on the Developers Console.

Comment: Can you able to provide any documentation regarding this. As per my knowledge developer console project shows the quota alone, but it didn't mention that quota is separate for IMAP and GMAIL REST API